# C# method observable

Tags: c#, observable

I have a method that is called whenever something happens. It can be called any number of times. Then method returns a Task. Basically I want to setup an "obserable" for when ever this method is called. I have no control over the method being called. The method that is called is virtual so I can override it an see that it gets called. But I would rather setup an "observable". So I have something like

```
class Foo
{
  void Bar()
}
```

Again I have no control over Foo but I have an instance of it.

```
var instanceofFoo = new Foo();
```

I want to setup an "observable" that will be triggered anytime that `instanceOfFoo.Bar` is called.

The reason that I want an "observable" is because I don't want to have to setup the "observer" again for possibly the next call. I am coding in C# and I looked at `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` but there it specifically indicated that the "provider" had to implement `IObservable<T>`. Since I don't have control over the provider (in this case the instance of Foo) I cannot use this. I looked at Rx.NET but was unable to glean from the examples something that fit this situation. To further complicate things assume that the instance of Foo is a dependency of another class like

```
class FooService
{
    public bool wasCalled { get; set; }
    public FooService(Foo f)
    {
       // TODO: Setup code to trigger when f.Bar() is called
    }
}
```

This setup would need to be able to be cleanly torn down so that there are no dangling "subscribers".

So the flow would be something like this

1. var foo = new Foo();
2. var fooService = new FooService(foo);
3. foo.Bar();
4. Assert.IsTrue(fooService.wasCalled);

Ideas?

Comment: You keep using the word "observable" within quotes as if you mean to confer some meaning that you are about to explain-- but then you never get around to explaining it. So I am left wondering what you mean, specifically. Can you either make some effort to find the correct terminology? Or explain in plain terms without using undefined neologisms? I'm guessing you want some kind of `event` or you want code to execute before or after `Foo` is called.

Comment: If you can override the method then one option could be to override the method, call the base method and then trigger your notification event.

Comment: It is possible you are looking for "interception" - if you would use Unity for DI and the method you trying to see called is part of some interface (or at least virtual) it should be doable. If you can't control *creation* of `Foo` you'd look for some sort of assembly rewriting I guess.

Comment: Wrap it in your own type that you control and only access it through your type.

Comment: @JohnWu I say "observable" like the way RXjs defines observables. From what I see C# doesn't have an equivalent concept. I don't want an event for testing purposes.  For testing I would like to mock the dependency so when I place a mocked call for Bar() I can observe the consequences in the FooService.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you focus on "observables", but C# has a system for subscriber/publisher type of interaction already, namely [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/).

You can use the Proxy pattern combined with inheritance to achieve what you want:

```
class FooEventProxy : Foo
{
    public event EventHandler BarCall;

    /*
     *   Retype all constructors of Foo here and delegate them to base.
     */

    public override void Bar()
    {
        OnBarCall(new EventHandler());
        base.Bar();
    }

    protected virtual void OnBarCall(EventHandler e)
    {
        EventHandler event = BarCall;

        if (event != null)
        {
            event(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming that you control the creation of `Foo` and can just force all places it's created to use `FooEventProxy` instead.

If you can't then you just found out the reason for keeping all your creation logic in factories and the situation is a bit more complicated. If you can access all the arguments of `Foo` that it was instantiated with you can probably just copy them over to the new instance of `FooEventProxy`. If you can't then we're in a conundrum: you want to replace an argument of type `Foo` with `FooEventProxy`, but you can't ensure that the internal state of the argument will be correctly transferred into the new instance. You can't just route the virtual method calls to the wrapped instance, since the non-virtual methods can still be called and will not work correctly - violation of the Liskov principle. So you need to either copy the internal state of `Foo` exactly into `FooEventProxy` using massive reflection voodoo or, well, you're out of luck and you've just found out the reason for depending on interfaces/abstracts and not concrete classes.

I don't know how to copy over all base class data from an existing instance to a new instance of a derived type off the top of my head, so if you  really think that's what you want, please ask another question specifically for that.

Comment: I would like to avoid events as I am interested in testing. For testing I would like to mock the dependency so when I place a mocked call for Bar() I can observe the consequences in the FooService.( a method is called some property is changed. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is just for unit testing. I can provide you with two answers, depending on your constraints.

If you are able to modify the code, then the best (and most [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)) approach is to depend on an interface instead of a concrete class, wrapping if necessary. Then in your unit tests you can substitute a method call that calls the original method but also does something else (e.g. logs it).

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Bar() { }
}
```

Then in your test code:

```
class FooShim : IFoo
{
    protected readonly Foo _foo;
    protected readonly Action _action;

    public FooShim(Foo foo, Action action) 
    {
         _foo = foo;
         _action = action;
    }

    public Bar()
    {
        action();
        _foo.Bar();
    }
}


//Arrange
bool wasCalled = false;
var foo = new FooShim(new Foo(), () => wasCalled = true);
var fooService = new FooService(foo);

//Act
fooService.DoSomethingThatCallsFoo();

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(wasCalled);
```

If you are not able to modify the code, you can do something similar, but you will need a special framework like [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=html%2FM_Typemock_Isolator_VisualBasic_TheseCalls_WillBeReplacedWith.htm). TypeMock takes advantage of .NET CLR internals to allow you to intercept and replace method calls.

```
Isolate.WhenCalled( () => foo.Bar()).WillBeReplacedWith( () => wasCalled = true );
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this solution is that it seems backwards to me. Basically it is calling a method in fooService and then checking that the method in FooShim was called. What I was looking for was calling a method on the dependency and Asset'ing something on FooService changed.So say that wascalled is a property on the FooService I would like to assert wasCalled to be true when the method on the dependency was called.

Comment: Your example and your explanation are not clear to me. If you just want to assert that some property has changed, I don't see any need for interception-- your test code can just inspect the property after the call returns. Perhaps you could add some additional code to your question to clarify.

Comment: I have a class FooService that depepends on Foo or IFoo. Either way there is a Bar method on Foo. When I call the Bar method on Foo or IFoo I want to be able to assert that a property changed on FooService. So the flow would be something like: 1) var foo = new Foo(); 2) var fooService = new FooService(foo). 3) Call the Foo method foo.Bar() 4) Assert(fooService.wasCalled == true).

Comment: What's wrong with the code you just wrote in the comment? Where is it that you need an observable or observable-like behavior?

Comment: It is the connection between the property wasCalled and the call to the method Bar() that I am missing?

Comment: If `wasCalled` is false before the call to `Bar()`, and it is true afterward, I think you can infer that `Bar()` set it to true. What further connection do you need?

Comment: True. That is what I want to see. What i am missing is how the call to Bar() changes the property wasCalled?

Comment: You can pass any action you want. For example, you could change `() => wasCalled = true` to `() => foo.wasCalled = true` if you need to set a property of `foo`. Does that suit your purposes?

Comment: I am not clear about the action. The only dependency is Foo or IFoo. Would you be able to show a full example?